# .NET interoperability between Visual studio solution and running application

Tags: .net, web-applications, compilation, projects-and-solutions

Modifications to .ASPX pages make the ASP.NET compiler recompile the website automatically. I'm currently in a situation where templates are compiled in code and cached in a variable. The compilation process runs when the application starts this is good (should *not* be on every request). When new template files are added to the solution, or when existing templates are modified the compilation process should be run once again ideally.

**Is it possible to invoke a function from Visual studio into my application? Or is there some design flaw here?** This all takes place during development phase, not when in production.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I started using a [FileSystemWatcher](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.aspx) which does what I need quite efficiently.